# cannot access to my session

Tags: 18.04

I changed the name of the /home/mary folder to /home/alex using the following command:
mv /home/mary /home/alex
I restart my pc, I enter my password it loads and redisplays the same page (enter the password) I can not access my session, I think I made a serious mistake when I changed the name of the folder, is there a way to solve this problem I have very important data on my pc

Comment: Can you log in to a CLI virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F3 etc.)?

Comment: I click on ctrl + alt + F3 when I am on the login page and it blocks I can not move the cursor or anything. nothing is displayed I will wait even more time

Comment: If login on tty does not work you need to use a live session. Or grub rescue to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have very important data on my pc

Important data means you have a backup. So you could restore that. That way all you need to worry about is getting a user you can log into. See below.

> mv /home/mary /home/alex

Why did you think that was a good idea?

Files like `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` as an example do not get updated when you move a user.

The way to do this: create a 2nd user called alex from the "users" option in settings, make it an admin. Then log into alex, confirm it works. Then copy all personal files over to `/home/alex` and do a `chown -R $USER:$USER /home/alex` while logged in as alex. Do not copy over hidden files. Confirm it works and only then you remove user mary using the `deluser` command. Not by removing `/home/mary`

To fix the current problem:

- Use a live session or grub rescue to get to a command line.

It MIGHT work to just do `chown -R alex:alex /home/alex` but if it does not you pile another problem onto this problem.

So the procedure would be ...

From command line:

Start by copying (not moving) everything back to `/home/mary`.
Confirm if logging into mary works. If not do a `chown -R mary:mary /home/mary` and try again.
If it does work remove `/home/alex` (so actual `rm` and not `deluser` since there  is no user alex, only a directory) and proceed with the method listed above.

Also have a look at `.xsession-errors`. That is where errors are logged.

Comment: I'll follow your step and I'll sign if it's ok or not. thank you so much

Comment: nope. You mount your partition. It will be in /media/{disk name}/home/  @mzlle add any questions or problems you have into the question. I'll get a notification when you do and will add to my answer if I can :) Another thing: you can mount the disk and then copy files to a 2nd usb disk if need be. Then you have those files saved.

Comment: I chose to use the live session method, while waiting for the iso image of ubuntu to download (slow connection from another windows laptop ), I found that the command ctrl alt F3 on which I clicked for a long time was able to open the virtual terminal, in which I renamed my folder from alex to mary again : mv /home/alex  /home/mary , the problem is solved ,now i can access to my session thank you very much Rinzwind & steeldriver & user68186

Comment: cool! well done @mzlle If my answer is good enough do accept it (that will remove it from then open answers queue)

Comment: yes it's very good, Done ;)